# Makefile: No rule to make target /hello.obj

Tags: makefile

```
SRCDIR=src
OUTDIR=bin

CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O0 -g -MD -fmodules-ts

rwildcard=$(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))
CODEFILES := $(call rwildcard,src,*.cpp)

OBJFILES := $(subst $(SRCDIR),,$(CODEFILES:%.cpp=%.obj))

$(info $(OBJFILES))

all: $(OBJFILES)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

%.obj:%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $(OUTDIR)/$@ $(SRCDIR)/$<
```

Outputs:

```
/hello.obj /main.obj /some/bye.obj
make: *** No rule to make target '/hello.obj', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

It's my first time using a Makefile and I'm stuck on this problem.  What did I do wrong?

PS: This is on Windows.

EDIT:

```
$(info $(CODEFILES))
```

gives:

```
PS F:\CLionFiles\modules> make
 src/hello.cpp src/main.cpp     src/some/bye.cpp
make: *** No rule to make target '/hello.obj', needed by 'all'.  Stop
```

Comment: With the `all` target, you're trying to create a file called `all`?

Comment: Are you sure this is on Windows?  Doesn't Windows use backslashes in file paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of `CODEFILES` all start with `src/`.  When you define `OBJFILES` with `subst`, you strip off `SRCDIR` (which is `src`) which leaves the resultant file paths starting with `/`.

You want to put the object files in `OUTDIR`.  So, you need to do

```
OBJFILES := $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OUTDIR),$(CODEFILES:%.cpp=%.obj))
```

You then need to change the final recipe to

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.obj: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```